# How to combine two values from child components with an event?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript-vue

I can't assign data from child component.

I am simply trying to implement [emitting a specific value with an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event)

Child component is:

```html
<template>

    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" width="210" height="210"
        backgroundColor="blue" color="white">
        <Label text="Father" row="0" col="1"
            class="h2 text-center p-t-5 text-primary" />
        <ListPicker :items="maleName" v-model="maleIndex" row="1" col="1"
            @selectedIndexChange="selectedIndexofFatherChanged" />
    </StackLayout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                maleName: [
                    "Rey",
                    "Antonia",
                    "Victor",
                    "Lincoln",
             
                ],
                maleIndex: 0
            };
        },
        methods: {
            selectedIndexofFatherChanged() {
                this.$emit("fatherChanged", this.fatherName);
                // console.log("changed to: " + this.fatherName);
            }
        },
        computed: {
            fatherName() {
                return this.maleName[this.maleIndex];
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

and Parent Component is:

```html
<template>
    <Page>
        <ActionBar title="Choose Parent" />
        <GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="*,90">
            <SelectMother col="0" @motherChanged="onMotherChanged">
            </SelectMother>
            <SelectFather col="1" @fatherChanged="onFatherChanged">
            </SelectFather>
            <Button text="Show Result" @tap="onButtonTap" row="2"
                colSpan="2" />
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    import SelectMother from "./SelectMother";
    import SelectFather from "./SelectFather";

    export default {
        components: {
            SelectMother,
            SelectFather
        },
        data() {
            return {
                motherName: null,
                fatherName: null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            onButtonTap() {
                alert("father: " + this.fatherName + " mother: " + this
                    .motherName);
            },
        },
        watch: {
            onFatherChanged(nameFromComponent) {
                nameFromComponent = this.fatherName;
            },
            onMotherChanged(nameFromComponent) {
                nameFromComponent
                    = this.motherName;
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

When I console log payload in `onFatherChanged` method it turns *null*

**How to combine father and mother and show results.**

1. Select Father from child component
2. Select Mother  from second child component
3. Assign incoming payload and Show Results

---

[image]

---

### Please check [{N} Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Dez2fV&v=26)

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Dez2fV&v=26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```js
onFatherChanged(payload) {
                payload = this.fatherName;
                console.log(payload);
            },
```

It should be;

```js
onFatherChanged(payload) {
                this.fatherName = payload;
                console.log(payload);
            },
```